# Python print to file function is not printing to file

Tags: python

I am using the print function with output to file argument. The print function is under an if statement. Below is the code

```
log_file = open("Src_files.log", 'w') 
if count_1.equals(count_2) == False:
    print('Error: Discrepancy with processed file. Count of records does not match with sources file', file=log_file)
```

Count_1 and count_2 are unequal dataframes

The code gets executed without throwing any error but when I check the log file, it does not contain the printed statement.

How do I correct the code?

Comment: Firstly try closing the file.

Comment: 1) Please provide a [mcve] 2) Are you sure your app is entering the if-block? 3) What happens if you use an absolute file path instead of a relative one?

Comment: what is the value of count_1 and count_2?

Comment: use with while opening file and it will handle exception and file closing. check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` does not flush by default. check the python [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) to find that there is a `flush` keyword arg, or simply close the file. `log_file.close()`

Comment: Adding the flush argument worked